# Angular JS directive doesn't work on server after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, minify

This directive doesn't work on server after minification. It gives the following error:

> ```
> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-%20gwsRegexDirective
>     at angular.js:99
>     at angular.js:4905
>     at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:5065)
>     at angular.js:4910
>     at d (angular.js:5065)
>     at e (angular.js:5090)
>     at Object.invoke (angular.js:5114)
>     at angular.js:8756
>     at r (angular.js:387)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8754)
> ```

```
     app.directive('gwsRegex', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                element.bind('keyup', () => {
                    let _regex = new RegExp(attrs['gwsRegex']);
                    var _value = element[0].value;
                    if (_value.match(_regex)) {
                        element[0].value = _value.replace(_value.match(_regex)[0], '').trim()
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AngularJS minified js files not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240654/angularjs-minified-js-files-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Parameter name shrinking done during minification breaks AngularJS's dependency injection. For example, "$compile" might become "d". You have to use the alternative syntax where the names of the services are specified as strings. Instead of the second argument passed to `app.directive` being a function, it's an array where the final element is that function and all the prior elements are the service names in the same order they appear in the function's param list.

Here's an example with an extra dependency added so you can see how the order matters.

```js
app.directive('gwsRegex', 
  [
    '$compile', '$timeout', 
    function ($compile, $timeout) {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
              element.bind('keyup', () => {
                  let _regex = new RegExp(attrs['gwsRegex']);
                  var _value = element[0].value;
                  if (_value.match(_regex)) {
                      element[0].value = _value.replace(_value.match(_regex)[0], '').trim()
                  }
              });
          }
      };
    }
  ]
);
```